# "not in" in Core Data

Tags: iphone, sql, core-data

I'm newbie in objective C and I need to execute a query that in php might be as follow:

```
$alreadyDone = array();
do {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id NOT IN (".implode(",", $alreadyDone).")";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $n = mysql_num_rows($res);
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        // do some stuff
        $alreadyDone[] = $r['id'];
    }
} while ($n > 1);
```

My first question is: is there a function similar to the sql "NOT IN"?

However I try to make it by myself, I then selected the rows and put it in the `NSArray *alreadyDone`.
Second question: how can I build a query in Core Data with `NSPredicate` to compare a field with an object I already own, in the example each element of `alreadyDone`?

Thanks a lot for answer and sorry for my English (I am Italian).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Predicates have a compound `NOT IN` although it's slightly different in syntax. You would need something like:

```
NOT (name IN { 'Ben', 'Melissa', 'Matthew' })
```

You can substitute an array variable as needed.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that in Core Data I don't have an explicit ID field, and the name could be the same. How can I tell Core Data to use the Users* object for matching?